# Reordering columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am using the summarise_all function in an attempt to create a table for 30 different variables.

```
df <- RATIOS

df.sum <- df %>% 
  select(X1Y, X2Y, X3Y, X4Y, X5Y) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(min = min, 
                     max = max,
                     mean = mean,
                     first = first))
```

This first section of code works as intended.  Now I am trying to organize the data into a table similar to excel however when I hand check the max, min, etc. they values are incorrect.

```
df.stats.tidy <-
  df.sum %>% 
  gather(stat, val) %>%
  separate(stat, into = c("var", "stat"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(stat, val) %>%
  select(min, max, mean, first) # reorder columns

print(df.stats.tidy)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United       States.1252   
 [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252   LC_NUMERIC=C                          
 [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

  other attached packages:
  [1] tidyr_0.8.2 dplyr_0.7.8

  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.3.0        
   [5] magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.3.0     rlang_0.3.0.1    stringi_1.2.4   
   [9] bindrcpp_0.2.2   tools_3.4.3      glue_1.3.0       purrr_0.2.5     
   [13] compiler_3.4.3   pkgconfig_2.0.2  bindr_0.1.1           tidyselect_0.2.5
   [17] tibble_1.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work as intended for me? First, some toy data:

```
library("tidyverse")

# Make some toy data
set.seed(1)
n <- 5
df <- tibble("X1Y" = runif(n), "X2Y" = runif(n), "X3Y" = runif(n), 
             "X4Y" = runif(n), "X5Y" = runif(n))

print(df)
```

```
 ## A tibble: 5 x 5
#    X1Y    X2Y   X3Y   X4Y   X5Y
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.266 0.898  0.206 0.498 0.935
#2 0.372 0.945  0.177 0.718 0.212
#3 0.573 0.661  0.687 0.992 0.652
#4 0.908 0.629  0.384 0.380 0.126
#5 0.202 0.0618 0.770 0.777 0.267
```

Now, we run your code:

```
df.sum <- df %>% 
  select(X1Y, X2Y, X3Y, X4Y, X5Y) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(min = min, 
                 max = max,
                 mean = mean,
                 first = first))

df.stats.tidy <- 
  df.sum %>% 
  gather(stat, val) %>%
  separate(stat, into = c("var", "stat"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(stat, val) %>%
  select(var, min, max, mean, first)  # Keeping "var" here 

print(df.stats.tidy)
```

```
## A tibble: 5 x 5
#  var      min   max  mean first
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 X1Y   0.202  0.908 0.464 0.266
#2 X2Y   0.0618 0.945 0.639 0.898
#3 X3Y   0.177  0.770 0.445 0.206
#4 X4Y   0.380  0.992 0.673 0.498
#5 X5Y   0.126  0.935 0.438 0.935
```

For example, the max of X4Y is 0.992, which agrees with visual inspection above.

**Edit:** From the talk in the comments, the `var` does not change the ordering for me:

```
df.sum %>% 
   gather(stat, val) %>%
   separate(stat, into = c("var", "stat"), sep = "_") %>%
   spread(stat, val) %>%
   select(min, max, mean, first) 
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#     min   max  mean first
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.202  0.908 0.464 0.266
#2 0.0618 0.945 0.639 0.898
#3 0.177  0.770 0.445 0.206
#4 0.380  0.992 0.673 0.498
#5 0.126  0.935 0.438 0.935

df.sum %>% 
   gather(stat, val) %>%
   separate(stat, into = c("var", "stat"), sep = "_") %>%
   spread(stat, val) %>%
   select(var, min, max, mean, first)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  var      min   max  mean first
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 X1Y   0.202  0.908 0.464 0.266
#2 X2Y   0.0618 0.945 0.639 0.898
#3 X3Y   0.177  0.770 0.445 0.206
#4 X4Y   0.380  0.992 0.673 0.498
#5 X5Y   0.126  0.935 0.438 0.935
```

Comment: that is very very strange because I cant seem to get the same results on my end....

Comment: so I added the var column and the data is correct, however the variables are not listed in order.

Comment: @BrianSteeves Sorry to ask, but are you absolutely sure? I get the same ordering with and without adding `var` in the select function. Be sure to restart R to have a fresh session (in case old variables are messing things up).

Comment: I restarted R and yes I am 100% positive the variables are not in order...its very very strange.

Comment: Weird. Can you run `sessionInfo()` and post the results in your post?

Comment: I figured it out... my actual code has X1Y going all the way through X30.... I excluded all of them from the original code because of length... it looks like its ordering the variables using the first number and not necessarily the second.